# adding comments and likes to an article page

Tags: blog, social, comments, like

As it is common in many organizations there is a roll up of 'news' based on article pages that feeds a content search web part. All of a sudden the requirement is to be able to 'like' and 'comment' the articles.

I would like to know if someone tried to create the comment/like function 'manually' and the steps taken. My other (preferred) option would be to completely scrap the article pages and start anew from a blog (which has likes and comments automatically), however I would like to be prepared in case the blog option is rejected.

Comment: have you tried enabling ratings on your page library?

Comment: Yammer feed: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Embed-a-Yammer-feed-into-a-SharePoint-site-4817d2fa-50f6-4f25-88a0-a312745768d4

Comment: yes, but adding the ratings on the page requires editing the page in sharepoint designer.

Comment: Enabling ratings at a library level shouldn't involve any sharepoint designer work- which site template are you using?

Comment: the rating/like needs to be visible on the page and not in the page library view only

Comment: Add these two content types to your page library: Enterprise Wiki Page and Project Page. Create a page with any of those layouts - you should see a ratings control on the page itself.